# SQL Two columns from a single row based on Third Column

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have a dataset (Call it TableA) that records all data for a single year, in columns by month

[image]

What I want to do is be able to use a single query to get a beginning and ending balance for the first month on a single row, but that would require pulling in the Balance 12 from the previous year.  similar to this:

[image]

I need to be able to do this as a Direct Query in PowerBI, so merging separate queries in PowerQuery won't work.

Are there any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CurrentYear.Item, CurrentYear.FiscYr, PreviousYear.Balance12, CurrentYear.Balance1 
FROM TableA CurrentYear
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA PreviousYear ON CurrentYear.Item = PreviousYear.Item AND PreviousYear.FiscYr = CurrentYear.FiscYr - 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This got me on the path to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select item, fiscyr, lag(balance12) over (partition by item order by fiscyr) as beginning,
       balanc1 as ending
from t;
```